Configuring Outlook SMTP on Website Contact Us page using Node JS
I am trying to configure outlook email for a client website contact us page using SMTP but getting an error related to authentication:
" [0] Error: Invalid login: 535 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful [MA0PR01CA0059.INDPRD01.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM 2024-04-06T09:43:31.279Z 08DC55931D44CA62]
[0] at SMTPConnection._formatError (/home/abhishek/Academy_Website/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:790:19)
[0] at SMTPConnection._actionAUTHComplete (/home/abhishek/Academy_Website/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:1564:34)
[0] at SMTPConnection.<anonymous> (/home/abhishek/Academy_Website/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:1518:18)
[0] at SMTPConnection._processResponse (/home/abhishek/Academy_Website/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:969:20)
[0] at SMTPConnection._onData (/home/abhishek/Academy_Website/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:755:14)
[0] at SMTPConnection._onSocketData (/home/abhishek/Academy_Website/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:193:44)
[0] at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:513:28)
[0] at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:324:12)
[0] at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:297:9)
[0] at Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:234:10) {
[0] code: 'EAUTH',
[0] response: '535 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful [MA0PR01CA0059.INDPRD01.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM 2024-04-06T09:43:31.279Z 08DC55931D44CA62]',
[0] responseCode: 535,
[0] command: 'AUTH LOGIN' "


The website is built on nodejs and here is the controller code I am using:
const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
host: "smtp.office365.com", // Outlook/Office 365 SMTP server
port: 587, // Port for TLS/STARTTLS
secure: false, // true for 465, false for other ports
auth: {
user: process.env.EMAIL_ADDRESS, // Your Outlook/Office 365 email address
pass: process.env.EMAIL_PASSWORD, // Your Outlook/Office 365 password
},
tls: {
ciphers: "SSLv3",
},
});

Seems we are stuck on this point. Any suggestions on how to move forward with this?
Searching online seems to suggest that this is to do something with security defaults of the organization to be altered using "Microsoft Entra" admin logon, but I couldn't find an option to disable them specifically for this user and leave it intact for all other users.

Office 365 no longer allows Basic auth with SMTP, you need to use OAuth.

Thanks for the update. I am slightly new to this, would you be able to share any reference example and/or documentation for an implementation using Nodemailer ?

I know nothing about Nodemailer, sorry.

Basic auth over SMTP can still be used (though is now disabled by default).  There are some other options too (though note SMTP basic auth deprecation has now been announced): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/mail-flow-best-practices/how-to-set-up-a-multifunction-device-or-application-to-send-email-using-microsoft-365-or-office-365
